# Calculate these multiple percentages in PHP?

Tags: php, math

Say I have 5 users. Each user will receive their payment based on their individual percentage.

For eg.

```
User 1: 5%
User 2: 10%
User 3: 15%
User 4: 15%
User 5: 5%
```

Now say I have a total of $100.  I want to divide the $100 among the 5 users. But the users with higher %  will receive a higher amount than the the ones with lower %.

How would I calculate this?

Comment: So user 1 would get 5% of $100, which is $5?

Comment: Where do the remaining 50% go?

Comment: your percentages don't add to 100 - they add up to 50.

Comment: You need to work out the factor to divide by for each case, add those totals together, 5,10,15,15,5 = 50, so for each 1% of their totals, that's 2% of the grand total. as 100 / 50 = 2. As another example, if their totals add up to 25, thats 100/25 = 4 per one of their percentages.

Comment: Their combined percentage doesn't matter. New eg. Instead of 5 users, there are 100 users  with a mix of 5%,10%,15% each. And there is $100. How would you divide that $100 among 100 users, given their individual percentage?

Comment: The combined percentage is how you work out the proportionate percentage for each user be it 5 or 1 million

Comment: The math still works, if there's 100 users with 2% each, thats 100/200 = 0.5 which is how you determine the percentage to allocate from your total of . In the case of 100 with 2% they would end up with 0.5 dollars each from the $100 dollar total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would treat them as "unknowns", as you want to split the whole $100 among all, I would go that way:

```
User 1: 5% (5X)
User 2: 10% (10X)
User 3: 15% (15X)
User 4: 15% (15X)
User 5: 5% (5X)
```

**Simple equation:**

5X + 10X + 15X + 15X + 5X = 100

50X = 100

X = 2

```
User 1 gets 5*2 = $10 
User 2 gets 10*2 = $20 
User 3 gets 15*2 = $30 
User 4 gets 15*2 = $30 
User 5 gets 5*2 = $10
```

Comment: I don't think I was clear before. I am giving you a 5 users example. This could easily be 100 users or 1000 users with same percentages. So their total percentage doesn't matter. Only the individual percentage. For new eg.  Say there are 100 users with a mix of 5%,10%,15% each. But there is only $100. How would you divide that $100 among those 100 users, given their percentage?

Comment: @Tom you may misunderstand his answer, it is in fact the answer to your question.

Comment: I am seeing that he's multiplying to get a total of $100. What if the amount is $500 instead? How would it work?

Comment: @tom, you treat it as percents, however, I would offer you to look on each user as a part of a pie, a chunk, that way no matter how many users you have, and no matter what would be the "whole" part, you will always get the answer you're looking for.

Comment: @tom, that would work for any amount, try it and see that's exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Using the same user values for 500 dollars, the totals for each user added = 50. $500 / 50 = $10, that's $10 dollars per 1 user percent. User 1 gets 5 * 10 Dollars = $50, User 2 = $100, User 3 = $150, User 4 = $150, User 5 = $50 All those totals add up to $500

Comment: I think that makes sense. I will try it out.  Thanks.